# I am getting a java.lang.NullPointerException with jexcel

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

In Android, I am using jexcel api to write an excel document:

```
package com.xls;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import java.io.*;
import jxl.*;
import jxl.write.*; 
import jxl.write.biff.RowsExceededException;

public class ExcelActivity extends Activity {
    WritableWorkbook workbook;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        try {
            workbook = Workbook.createWorkbook(new File("output.xls"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        WritableSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("First Sheet", 0);  
       //nullPointerException here
    }
}
```

Can't start the Activity because of NullPointerException, Why?

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(455): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity 
ComponentInfo{com.xls/com.xls.ExcelActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1748)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1764)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:122)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1002)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4025)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

What causes this error?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the stack trace, it looks like your code attempts to dereference a null pointer, hence the NullPointerException.  Look at line 26 as suggested in the stack trace.  I believe this is the following:

```
WritableSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("First Sheet", 0);
```

did you check that `Workbook.createWorkbook(new File("output.xls"))` returns a non-null object before this point?